# icu::SimpleDateFormat use of undefined type compiler error

Tags: c++, icu

I cannot figure out why the following code (ICU example) will not compile:

```
void test()
{
    icu::Locale locale = icu::Locale("en");
    UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
    DateTimePatternGenerator* generator =
        DateTimePatternGenerator::createInstance(locale, status);

    UnicodeString pattern =
        generator->getBestPattern(UnicodeString("MMMd"), status);

    SimpleDateFormat* formatter = 
        new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, locale, status);
}
```

The error is: error C2027: use of undefined type 'icu_62::SimpleDateFormat'

The IDE is giving the message: **"forward declaration, incomplete type is not allowed".**

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I included the following header to solve the problem:

```
#include "unicode/smpdtfmt.h"
```